# How to change UILable text color change for a certain words?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

Say i have UIlabel and i want to change color of text at certain word. For example my label text is 
"Shop now and get up 50% off Select shoes Limited time offer"

i which "50%" and "Limited" want change color

predefined some word if accrue  in label text then change color. fist find and then change color and font or sub string.

Comment: Have you tried NSMutableAttributedString ?

Answer (score 1):

**To do this use NSAttributedString:**

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *text = 
 [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] 
   initWithAttributedString: label.attributedText];

[text addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
             value:[UIColor redColor] 
             range:NSMakeRange(10, 1)];
[label setAttributedText: text];
```

For details :https://github.com/joaoffcosta/UILabel-FormattedText

Answer (score 0):

You can use     `NSMutableAttributedString`

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Shop now and get up 50% off Select shoes Limited time offer"];
    [str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(, )];
    [str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(, )];
```

Comment: dear how to find predefined words that want to change color like 
"50%" and "Limited"
i not now range run time check if 50% and Limited in this label then change color.